# Heaping a binary tree

Tags: c, algorithm, search, heap, binary-tree

I am learning about heaping and I am having trouble understand how you are supposed to move each node.I will give you an example tree below:

```
          1
      /      \
     2        3
   /  \      /  \
  4    5    6    7
 / \   /
8   9 10
```

So that is my tree. I am trying to get 10 to the node but do not understand the steps that I take. Would I first look at the bottom of the tree? Heres my attempts:

```
          1
      /      \
     2        3
   /  \      /  \
  4    5    6    7
 / \   /
8   9 10 


 -> Move ten up and the two down. 

          1      
      /      \
    10        3
   /  \      /  \
  4    5    6    7
 / \   /
8   9 2 

-> Move the 9 up 

         1      
      /      \
    10        3
   /  \      /  \
  9    5    6    7
 / \   /
8   4 2 

-> move the 7 up

          1      
      /      \
    10        7
   /  \      /  \
  9    5    6    3
 / \   /
8   4 2

-> Move the whole left side up and bring the 1 down.

         10      
      /      \
    9         7
   /  \      /  \
  8    5    6    3
 / \   /
1   4 2
```

This is what I end up with but I have a feeling this is not right because it is not an ordered tree. Can someone help me understand where I went wrong?

Comment: Um, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_heap ... note that heaps aren't (necessarily) ordered, and heaping is something you do to turn your tree back into a heap, but you started out with a min heap ... are you trying to turn it into a max heap?

Comment: Yes I am trying order them in descending order

Comment: Again, a heap is not necessarily ordered. Your end result is a max heap, since it satisfies the two criteria at the link I gave.

Comment: Very interesting. As I went down the line I did not break any rules?

Comment: To turn a heap into a max heap, you start with the last parent, swap it with the larger of its children, and then move to the previous parent till you reach the root.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Heap is not an ordered binary tree. The only ordering that heap preserves is that any child node is less (or equal) than it's parent node. Child nodes at the same level of the tree can be in any order relatively to each other.